# how to force row in container that is flex to center vertically in bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap 5 container that needs to hold a dynamic grid of items that will eventually be widgets.  Each of the same size.  I need the contents of each widget to be centered vertically and horizontally within the widget itself. I use a row to allow the dynamic growth for number of widgets (each with a fixed height).

So far it is almost complete and working, but I can't figure out how to get the row to center vertically in the parent container. I have researched and attempted many solutions proposed on StackExchange but none seem to work in this scenario.

Current version:

```
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    <div class="my-auto">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center w-100">
            <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
                <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
                <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
                <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
                <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
                <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
                <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the  row inside the container to center vertically within the container?

Example here: https://codeply.com/p/0Kg0YjFHEz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by `min-vh-100`. Change it to `vh-100` and add `align-items-center h-100` to the `row`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container shadow vh-100 py-2">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
      <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
      <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
      <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
      <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
      <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 btn-outline-primary m-1 d-flex align-items-center" style="height:300px; border: 5px solid red;">
      <div class="mx-auto"> Widget </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```